# Python - process only new element of dictionnary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a unique (unique keys) dictionnary that I update adding some new keys depending data on a webpage.
and I want to process only the new keys that may appear after a long time. Here is a piece of code to understand :

```
a = UniqueDict()

while 1:

    webpage = update() # return a list

    for i in webpage:
        title = getTitle(i)
        a[title] = new_value # populate only new title obtained because it's a unique dictionnary

        if len(a) > 50:
            a.clear() # just to clear dictionnary if too big

    # Condition before entering this loop to process only new title entered
    for element in a.keys():
        process(element)
```

Is there a way to know only new keys added in the dictionnary (because most of the time, it will be the same keys and values so I don't want them to be processed) ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you might also do, is keep the processed keys in a set.
Then you can check for new keys by using set(d.keys()) - set_already_processed.
And add processed keys using set_already_processed.add(key)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an ordered dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys were first added.

Comment: The OrderedDict only remembers the order, but in my second loop, the dictionnary is still processed. Example: if I found 2 titles, I will add them to the dictionnary, then they will be processed but it in the second loop, this is the same title, they won't be added BUT they will still be processed..

Answer (score 0):

Make your own `dict` that tracks additions:

```
class NewKeysDict(dict):
    """A dict, but tracks keys that are added through __setitem__
    only. reset() resets tracking to begin tracking anew. self.new_keys
    is a set holding your keys.
    """    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(NewKeysDict, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.new_keys = set()

    def reset(self):
        self.new_keys = set()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(NewKeysDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        self.new_keys.add(key)


d = NewKeysDict((i,str(i)) for i in range(10))
d.reset()
print(d.new_keys)
for i in range(5, 10):
    d[i] = '{} new'.format(i)

for k in d.new_keys:
    print(d[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

> (because most of the time, it will be the same keys and values so I don't want them to be processed)

You get complicate !
The keys are immutable and unique.
Each key is followed by a value separated, by a colon.

```
dict = {"title",title}
text = "textdude"
dict["keytext"]=text
```

This is add a value textdude, with the new key called "keytext".
For check, we use "in".

```
"textdude" in dict
```

He return true

Comment: whoops, it's "keytext" in dict